# gym RL with MultiDiscrete ActionSpace AttributeError: 'MultiDiscrete' object has no attribute 'spaces'

Tags: python

I'm trying to build an Reinforcement Learning Algorithm, which can play the MasterMind Game. I'm using an MultiDiscrete Anction and Observation Space. The Action Space takes 4 slots with 6 colors each and the Observation Space is 2x4. I created an Custom Environment to connect with my programmed game. The Environment isnt ready yet due to the occuring error. Maybe someone can help me solving this issue.

```
import gym as gym
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box, MultiDiscrete, Dict
from stable_baselines3.common.policies import MultiInputActorCriticPolicy

action_space = MultiDiscrete(np.array([6,6,6,6]), dtype=int)
observation_space = MultiDiscrete(np.array([4,4]), dtype=int)

...

class MasterMindEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(MasterMindEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = action_space
        self.observation_space = observation_space

    def step(self, action:np.ndarray):
        pass_action(action)
        output = get_output()
        print(output)

        reward = output[0] + output[1]
        print(reward)
    
        done = False
        info = {}

        return observation_space.sample(), 1, done, info

    def reset(self):
        return self.observation_space.sample()
    
...

model = A2C(MultiInputActorCriticPolicy, env)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
```

And the Error is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\...\model.ipynb Zelle 10 in <module>
----> 1 model = A2C(MultiInputActorCriticPolicy, env)
      2 model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)


File c:\...\Python310\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\a2c\a2c.py:126, in         
A2C.__init__(self, policy, env, learning_rate, n_steps, gamma, gae_lambda, ent_coef,     
vf_coef, max_grad_norm, rms_prop_eps, use_rms_prop, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, 
normalize_advantage, tensorboard_log, create_eval_env, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, 
device, _init_setup_model)
    123     self.policy_kwargs["optimizer_kwargs"] = dict(alpha=0.99, 
eps=rms_prop_eps, weight_decay=0)
    125 if _init_setup_model:
--> 126     self._setup_model()

File c:\...\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\stable_baselines3\common\on_policy_algorithm.py:123, in 
OnPolicyAlgorithm._setup_model(self)
   112 buffer_cls = DictRolloutBuffer if isinstance(self.observation_space, 
gym.spaces.Dict) else RolloutBuffer
    114 self.rollout_buffer = buffer_cls(
    115     self.n_steps,
    116     self.observation_space,
   (...)
    121     n_envs=self.n_envs,
    122 )
--> 123 self.policy = self.policy_class(  # pytype:disable=not-instantiable
...
--> 258 for key, subspace in observation_space.spaces.items():
    259     if is_image_space(subspace):
    260         extractors[key] = NatureCNN(subspace, features_dim=cnn_output_dim)

AttributeError: 'MultiDiscrete' object has no attribute 'spaces'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was testing out my custom environment. This is all happening because of the MultiDiscrete Observation Space.

```py
self.observation_space = MultiDiscrete(max_machine_states_vec + [scheduling_horizon+2]) ### Observation space is the 0,...,L for each machine + the scheduling state including "ns" (None = "ns")
```

You need not change the observation space, change the algorithm you are using. A2C or PPO cannot handle MultiDiscrete Observation Spaces. DQN can handle them. So your code should import DQN.

```py
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
# All the in-between code
model = DQN('MlpPolicy', env, verbose = 1)
```

Hope your issue is solved now.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. The Problem with DQN is, it does not support MultiDiscrete Action Spaces. I need an algorithm with the ability to provide MultiDiscrete Spaces in Actions and Observation. A2C should be able to handle this. [StableBaselines](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/a2c.html). The new Exception is the one after the UPDATE mark on the website [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74152052/gym-rl-with-multidiscrete-actionspace-attributeerror-multidiscrete-object-has)